# Calling base method from one of the derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void func()
  {
    cout<<"A"<<endl;
  }
};

class B: public A
{};

class C: public B
{
public:
  virtual void func()
  {
    cout<<"C"<<endl;
  }
};

class D: public C
{
public:
  virtual void func()
  {
    //I don't want to use the class C's implementation
    //So I should call the next base function: B::func()
    //But since B does not re-define the virtual function, we might as well
    //directly call A::func()
    //But what is the correct practice? Call A::func() directly or call B::func()

    //A::func();
    //B::func();
  }
};

int main()
{
  A *ob;
  D dob;

  ob = &dob; ob->func();
  return 0;
}
```

I don't want to use the class C's implementation
So I should call the next base function: B::func()
But since B does not re-define the virtual function, we might as well directly call A::func()
But what is the correct practice? Call A::func() directly or call B::func()

Comment: PS: I know there is no difference, I just want to know what would be the "correct programming practice" in this situation.

Comment: There is none, it's up to you. (use `B::func` if you're not 100% certain that `B` doesn't redefine it, otherwise it's exactly the same, and there is no "best practice")

Comment: there is no 'correct programming practice'. It all depends on how do you continue in developing the project. Keep in mind a good design always makes the code easy to be read by others or even by you after some time :)

Comment: that is the exact argument we are having in my team. I have used B::func() in my code and some of my colleagues believe that A::func() is the right approach. Argument is regarding which makes code better to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real diffrence, since the B structure contains a copy of the `A::func()` itself - When a deriviate doesn't override the parent classes implementation, the function is copied. However, I believe casting the C object another time back to A from B would be less efficient, and thus I believe `B::func()` is the better way of the two.